# how to send binary object to Oracle NoSQL Database?

Tags: oracle-nosql

We are currently using a bitset to represent status of a series of chunks of work, each can be either success or failure in our Java Code. So we we want to find the most space-saving type to convert to in Oracle NoSQl. We think that the best solution is to use binary but we are hitting in the following issue when trying to insert data

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
PUT: Illegal Argument: Invalid driver type for Binary: ARRAY
```

In fact, I don't how to send binary object to Oracle NoSQL Database, any ideas?

If you need information about BitSet, please read

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a serialize/deserialize to JSON for your Java Objects. Here an example that show you, how to convert from/to BitSet to base64. Binary in JSON are stored in base64.

```
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.Base64;

public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
// Creating some examples of BitSet
BitSet first = new BitSet();
first.set(2); // 100
BitSet second = new BitSet();
second.set(4); // 10000
second.set(3); // 11000
BitSet third = new BitSet(2000);
third.set(5, 49);

// from Bitset to Base64
byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(first.toByteArray());
System.out.println("first="+first);
System.out.println("{'Chunk':'" +new String(encoded) + "'}");

encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(second.toByteArray());
System.out.println("second="+second);
System.out.println("{'Chunk':'" +new String(encoded) + "'}");
encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(third.toByteArray());

System.out.println("third="+third);
System.out.println("{'Chunk':'" +new String(encoded) + "'}");

// from Base64 to Bitset

byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode("4P8H");
BitSet four = BitSet.valueOf(decoded);
System.out.println("four="+four);

decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
BitSet thirdDecoded = BitSet.valueOf(decoded);
System.out.println("{'Chunk':'" +new String(encoded) + "'}");

System.out.println("third="+thirdDecoded);

}

}
```

the output BitSet to base64

```
first={2}
{'successfulChunkMask':'BA=='}
second={3, 4}
{'successfulChunkMask':'GA=='}
third={5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48}
{'successfulChunkMask':'4P//////AQ=='}
```

the output base64 to BitSet

```
4P8H in base64
four={5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}
{'successfulChunkMask':'4P//////AQ=='}

third={5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48}
```

If you use the NoSQL Java MapValue API (instead of JSON representation of your object) , you need transform from byte[] to Bitset and viceversa, and you don't need to pass trough base64. see toByteArray() and BitSet.valueOf(byte[]) in the code provided.

If you are inserting data using the NoSQL API and providing a JSON value, the solution is base64 for encoding your binary fields  (java.util.BitSet). Same if you are using the SQL APIs

Answer (score 0):

You can use BitSet.toByteArray() to create a byte[] array and then put that directly into an Oracle NoSQL FieldValue, which you can then write to the NoSQL database using put():

```
final FieldValue val = new BinaryValue(mybits.toByteArray());
```

When reading the value from Oracle NoSQL, you can generate the bitset back by calling BitSet.valueOf(byte[]).